# as3 can not move and rotate external image with movieClip

Tags: image, actionscript-3, load, external, movieclip

I spent so much time and did not do it.

I have a animated movieClip called holder1 (instance name) which is animated with 25 frames(moving and rotating). I can load external image, that is Ok. coordinates are ok, same with MovieClip. But it is not moving with holder1.
why?
earlier I could do it with loadmovie with as2.
thanks for your help.

```
  btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,f);

  var loader_mc : Loader = new Loader();
  var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest("imagem.jpeg");

 function f(e:Event){
 loader_mc.load(urlRequest);
  holder1.addChild(loader_mc);
  }
```

Comment: Possible causes: 1) there's more than one **holder1**, so the immobile one gets the loaded thing, or 2) **holder1** is not animated itself (means it stays at the same coordinates, rotation, etc) while the animation is on the timeline inside the **holder1**, this way animation just happens while loaded item just hovers above it on the next available child depth.

Comment: hi organis, I need a working example.can you help me?

Comment: I can, but that would be far too easy, wouldn't it? You should be the one to try, and fail, and try again all unless you **understand** how it works. Getting the working example from the start would be pointless as you gain no knowledge or experience from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,f);

var loader_mc : Loader = new Loader();
var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest("imagem.jpeg");

var speedX:int = 1;
var speedY:int = 1;

function f(e:Event){
    loader_mc.load(urlRequest);
    holder1.addChild(loader_mc);
    holder1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, andMove);
}

function andMove(e:Event){
    holder1.rotationZ += 1;
    if(holder1.x<0 || holder1.x>stage.stageWidth)
        speedX *= -1;
    if(holder1.y<0 || holder1.y>stage.stageHeight)
        speedY *= -1;
    holder1.x += speedX;
    holder1.y += speedY;    
}
```